# How to combine ListLogLogPlot and MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting, image-processing, visualization

Let's construct some data

```
data = Exp@Sort@RandomReal[10, 100];
col = Transpose@MapIndexed[Exp[First@#2/20] + #1 &, RandomReal[10, {100, 99}]];
```

The `data` and `col` look like this

```
g1 = ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
                          ImageSize -> 300]
g2 = MatrixPlot[col, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]
[image]

I want `g2` as background in `g1`, `Show[g1,g2]` can't be done.

Maybe transfer `Graphics` to `Image` and using `ImageTransformation` to make the `g2` have a logarithmic x-axis,  but I'm not familiar to Image Processing

Comment: You can look at `Overlay` to literally put one graphic on top of the other. You will have to put in some work to get a good alignment, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach is to use the `MatrixPlot` output as [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html) in a `Polygon` with [`ImageScaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageScaled.html) coordinates (so that its size stretches to the size of the image it sits in) and use the resulting stretchable graphics primitive as [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prolog.html) in `ListLogLogPlot`:

```
mp = MatrixPlot[col, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 300, ImagePadding -> 0, 
   DataReversed -> True, Frame -> False];
bg = {Texture[mp], Polygon[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]};
ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangeClipping -> True, Prolog -> bg]
```

[image]

An alternative approach is to  use the option `DataRange` in `MatrixPlot`:

```
mp2 = MatrixPlot[col, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 300, 
      DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 10}}];
ListLogLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  ImageSize -> 300,  Prolog -> mp2[[1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! But the code is a little difficult to understand, some functions haven't used before.

Comment: @partida, have a look at the examples in [Texture](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html), [ImageScaled](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageScaled.html), and [Prolog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prolog.html)

Comment: OK, thanks for providing the information