# How to combine MatrixPlot with ListPlot

Tags: plotting, matrix

I want to combine a ListPlot with a MatrixPlot.

I have a set of points to be used with a ListPlot. At the same time, I want to show a kind of heat map to show the intensity of their locations in a grid style map.

So, for example I have the data points:

```
data = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}
```

where the maximum and minimum of both x and y values are 0 and 10, respectively. Now I want to show that same points in a heat map of a 4x4 grid:

```
MatrixPlot[{{0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}]
```

where the matrix element `(4,0)` (lower left corner) corresponds to the `(0,0)` and the element `(0,4)` (upper right corner) corresponds to the `(10,10)` position.

Any idea on how shall I combine them? I'm aware of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178373/8555) answer but I confess I didn't understand it fully. But I suspect it does not fit to my case.

Comment: Maybe `ArrayPlot` ?

Comment: I think the problem is the same. Because the problem here is the combination. I want to show the heat map and on top of it the data that would go to ListPlot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Show[{MatrixPlot[{{0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 
     0}}, DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
  , Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Point[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Thanks exactly what I was looking for.